# Gibbs free energy ΔG=ΔG°+RTln(Kp) different expressions for ΔG

Tags: equilibrium

ΔG=ΔG°+RTln(Kp)

If I understand it correctly, the ΔG in this equation gives the "distance" in Gibbs free energy of a chemical system at a particular moment in a reaction (encoded by the Kp) to the gibbs free energy of the chemical system at equilibrium.
So when we write this in symbols 
for a general equilibrium reaction A + B <=> C + D:

ΣG(products at eq) + ΣG(reactants at eq) - (ΣG(products at k) + ΣG(reactants at k)) with k denoting a random point with certain concentrations in the reaction and eq denoting the equilibrium point.

However, ΔG is also ΣG(products at k) - ΣG(reactants at k).

So how are these two expressions for ΔG related? Basically how would you prove that

ΣG(products at eq) + ΣG(reactants at eq) - (ΣG(products at k) + ΣG(reactants at k)) 
= ΣG(products at k) - ΣG(reactants at k)

Comment: I can comprehend distance measured in [seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsec), but *distance in Gibbs free energy* is something new to me. Is it something related to the reaction coordinate? Also I'm not sure what exactly $ξ$ is here; I'm used to $ξ$ as [extent of reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extent_of_reaction) when used alongside with Gibbs energy, but here it seems more like an arbitrary reaction coordinate.

Comment: You're right, that's confusing so I edited it. I meant "distance" in the sense that this site uses it https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Thermodynamics/Chemical_Energetics/Free_Energy_and_Equilibrium

Comment: Oh. Then maybe you should've also quoted the word "distance" as your source did; it's more like a metaphor rather than a physical quantity.

Answer (score 1):

$K_p$ is normally reserved for equilibrium thus only apples when $\Delta G=0$ and conventionally $Q$ is used otherwise. In a plot of free energy $G$ vs extent of reaction $\zeta$, the slope is $(\partial G/\partial \zeta)_{T,p} =\Delta G$, and equilibrium occurs when the slope is zero then $\Delta G^\mathrm{o} =-RT\ln(K_p)$.  (The extent of reaction is zero with only reactants present, and 1 when one mole of reactants has become product.)

Thus to speak of 'distance' does not mean the energy difference from equilibrium as $\Delta G$ is the slope not the value of the energy $G$ vs $\zeta$.

In the sums you ask about, always calculate products - reactants. The only experimental quantities you have are the concentrations or pressures so it would be possible to calculate $\Delta G$, using your first equation, if the values are known at equilibrium and at some other point. This seems to be what you ask about.